# Single.fromPublisher subscribe and map to the return type reactivex java

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex, rx-java3

Using reactivex to map and return the value from the method as below

```
public Single<ProductViewModel> Create(ProductViewModel model) {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName(model.getName());
        product.setDescription(model.getDescription());
        product.setPrice(model.getPrice());

        return Single.fromPublisher(this.repository.getCollection("product", Product.class)
        .insertOne(product)).map(success -> {
             return new ProductViewModel(
                    success.getInsertedId(),
                    product.getName(),
                    product.getDescription(),
                    product.getPrice());
        });
    }
```

When I use the .map function the record is not inserted into the database, however, on the .subscribe method, the record is inserted successfully into the database.

But I want to map the inserted record and return the value to the consumer method.

Comment: It is not quite clear what the problem is. Could you please elaborate? When #getCollection#insertOne is laz, you have to subscribe to returned Single<ProductViewModel> in order to trigger the execution.

Comment: @HansWurst Yes,  I need to subscribe in order to execute, if I subscribe how can I map the success subscribe value and return from the method. I want to return the value of subscribing

Comment: This is not possible. The Single is a 'callback' container for composition of reactive data. In your case you do a DB-request, which does IO. You want to get called, when the operation finishes, in order not to block the main-thread. All side-effects resulting from this, should be done at a central point, which is the subscribe. If you want to call Create and wait for the result sync., while blocking the calling-thread use one of the blocking operators provided to you.